# Axios.Get not working inside a onEndEditing in app Release

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I have a react native app which I input a value to TextInput, then onEndEditing I call axios.get inside a function GetSKUOPAttributes(). The onEndEditing is working. At debug mode everything is working fine, only doesn't work in release. I've put an alert to check if the onEndEditing was working and it is. Could someone help me to findout why it doesn't work at release? The var opNumber and selectedLine have value inside.

```
function GetSKUOPAttributes() {
    alert('http://10.113.16.113:8082/api/skuattribute/find?OP=' + opNumber + '&line=' + selectedLine);
    axios.get('http://10.113.16.113:8082/api/skuattribute/find?OP=' + opNumber + '&line=' + selectedLine, {            
    }).then(function (response) {
        alert('Inside GetSKUOPAttributes');
        var temp = [];            
        response.data.map(r => InsertSKUAttribute(r.id, r.attributE_DESCRIPTION, r.sku,  r.value, r.status) ,console.log('INSIDE MAP'));         
        sleep(200);
        GetLocalAttributes();
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the app in debug mode but without the debugger (so that the console logs will be displayed in terminal instead of chrome debugger)? This is one way I use to see if I am using API not included in react or react-native. There are a few libraries that are supported by chrome engine but not by react-native engine on phones, so that is one scenario where you end up with things working in debug env but not in release app

Comment: also is ```http://10.113.16.113:8082``` a local IP address? If so, test if your phone can reach that IP using a phone browser

Comment: It is a local API, the device and the server with the API are in the same network. I have also tested the address at the browser from the android device and it can be reached and return the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long week I've found out what was the problem. And it was this Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.
So after many searches, many updates. The fix was very very simple.
All I needed was to add the tag bellow to AndroidManifest.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

I will let a link to the complete post if others, have the same issue.
https://freakycoder.com/react-native-notes-21-android-http-network-security-problem-fix-eeac4e1ea58b